# Automatic update of library version used in project in giltab README.md

Tags: gitlab, readme

Is there any easy way how to show a *library version* used in project in giltab **README.md / badge**, parsed directly from repository source code? I mean something automatic, I do not want to increase version in readme everytime it is changed in the source code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in solution ([open issue on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/26420))
My suggestion is to build your own script that reads the property from the source code, and replace it on your README.md file.
You can run this script as a job on your "release/deploy" stage.

---

P.S.
It's best to handle the versions using [git-tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) and not the source code itself.